# C#: How to use custom autocomplete source for textbox

Tags: c#

I would like to know how to make autocomplete source is choosed by the user, browse and load or import text file the text file is imported is arranged in order in reachtextbox or something.  If he wants edit to be comfortable and easy to use, even is that possible?

Comment: what are you having problems with?  This is very possible, but without a specific question to help assist with, save writing the entirety of the solution (which is far too broad), i'm not sure what you're hoping to get out of an answer.

Comment: If it possible post an answer ,, that user could import his source freely

Answer (score 3):

Read documentation carefully https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create the list to use as the custom source.  
    var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    source.AddRange(new string[]
                    {
                        "January",
                        "February",
                        "March",
                        "April",
                        "May",
                        "June",
                        "July",
                        "August",
                        "September",
                        "October",
                        "November",
                        "December"
                    });

    // Create and initialize the text box. 
    var textBox = new TextBox
                  {
                      AutoCompleteCustomSource = source,
                      AutoCompleteMode = 
                          AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend,
                      AutoCompleteSource =
                          AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource,
                      Location = new Point(20, 20),
                      Width = ClientRectangle.Width - 40,
                      Visible = true
                  };

    // Add the text box to the form.
    Controls.Add(textBox);
}
```

So, you need to get suggestions from somewhere into string[]. It can be an dictionary, txt file, binary file...once you get words into array you're good to go.

Comment: There is something still nuclear you set the source in the code or as msdn did but didn't say how the user could do ,, may be I should replace , January February and etc to richtextbox.text ?

Comment: Open the link, look at links on the left side of your screen, there is all you need, as for the exchange, make a Form.cs to do that, read file names from some txt file, or database. Many choices you have