# C# How to get int values from database in Textbox using AutoCompleteSource

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, sql-server-2008

I'm having a problem here which i can't solved. I have a textbox in my windows application. In that textbox i want to display a suggestion. In my database i have column name "Codeitem" and it is integer. i want to display this values on my texbox but i don't know how to do this. Any help guys. Thank you so much

```
AutoCompleteStringCollection Collection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection
  private void SIMSProduct_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        AddingProduct();

        using (var con = SQLConnection.GetConnection())
        {


            var select = new SqlCommand("Select Codeitem from employee_product", con);
            var reader = select.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Collection.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }       

        }

    }
private void txt_code_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        txt_code.AutoCompleteCustomSource = Collection;
        txt_code.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append;
        txt_code.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these 2 lines:
txt_code.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append;
txt_code.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;

where you've added:
txt_code.AutoCompleteCustomSource = Collection;

As a side note, make sure you use using () for reader and select . SqlCommands and SqlDataReaders should be disposed after use.

Comment: it's still doesn't show man, i added those two lines after my AutoCompleteSource. & can you elaborate more that dispose thingy that you mention.

Comment: Try adding some static values to Collection. This will help us narrow down where the issue is.  var Collection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
Collection .AddRange(new string[]
                    {
                        "January",
                        "February",
                        "March"
                    });

Comment: If these display, then we can look at what you're getting back from the db. If they don't display, it's probably an issue with how the textbox is configured. RE: the using suggestion, your code should be using (var select = new SqlCommand("Select Codeitem from employee_product", con)) { // inner code. }.  Same thing reader - using (var reader = select.ExecuteReader()) { //inner code }.

Comment: Already added it and try to input that values to my textbox but the suggestion still doesn't show. Should i remove my Sqldatareader ?

Comment: AutocompleteMode = SuggestAppend and AutocompleteSource = Custom source that's what i configure on my textbox properties

Comment: On the FormLoad event of your application, fill Collection with the values from your database as you are currently doing. Make Collection a class variable so it can be accessed by other methods.

On the TextChanged event, set txt_code.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append; txt_code.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource; txt_code.AutoCompleteCustomSource = Collection;

Comment: Also, make sure txt_code is referencing the correct textbox :)

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
I'm getting error to what you suggest  and it shows to Collection.Add(reader.GetString(0))

Comment: Not sure, what is throwing that error. Please update your code here with the latest.

Comment: Add brackets at the end of new AutoCompleteStringCollection . But what is throwing the object reference error?

Comment: It doesn't show the error anymore but why it is not displaying ? , I tried to create a new project and try to do it without using the values of database just the normal one with already collection ?

Comment: did the new project work? Everything looks good. Make sure you are referencing the correct textbox and also you dont have a RowFilter applied.

Comment: This is very Frustating , I solved my problem, autocomplete suggestion doesn't appear when textbox multi line is enabled

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_TextBox_AutoCompleteMode and the answer to your question already has been answered here: [C#: How to use custom autocomplete source for textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32291823/c-how-to-use-custom-autocomplete-source-for-textbox), you forgot to add:

```
AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

Comment: txt_code.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
      txt_code.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
Already added it but it still doesn't show. Is it right to put in on load event or textchanged event of textbox ?

Comment: You should put it on textchanged.